# Draw two semi-circles

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to fill a circle with two semi-circles. One on the left side and the other one on the right side. The circle on the left side should be black and the other side should be blue.

How do i achieve this? I tried to fill an ellipse and then draw a rectangle over the half of it. This works for one half of the circle. But with the other halfe i have a problem.

Any ideas how can draw the complete circle?

Comment: I picture of your desired result would help very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Graphics.DrawArc` to achieve this.

Create a windows forms application and drop this code into the form to test.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 320, 320);
    e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10), rect, 90, 180);
    e.Graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue), 10), rect, 270, 180);
}
```

Then change the rectangle coordinates to suit your needs.

Other things you might want to look at are, `DrawPie`, `FillPie`. Thinking logically, a pie which has two halves "should" draw two filled semi circles. The example above will just draw an outline of two semi-circles.