# How to draw a semicricle in C#?

Tags: c#

I found this code but I do not know how to use it in WinForms? My question is what do I need to do with this code step-by-step to draw a semicircle in a form.

```
        private void DrawEllipseRectangle(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create pen.
        Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

        // Create rectangle for ellipse.
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);

        // Draw ellipse to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(blackPen, rect);
    }
```

Comment: That appears to be winforms gdi+ code so... whats the question exactly?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836180/draw-two-semi-circles

Comment: The main problem I think is that you FOUND this code.
You didn't write it, so you didn't understand it.
A fast tutorial about GDI+
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gdi_plus12092005070041AM/gdi_plus.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Use `Graphics.DrawPie` to draw a pie-slice of a circle. A semi-circle is a pie-slice with a 180-degree sweep.